# Why is hashtagseen[] empty after I call the addposthashtags function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, object, meteor

I am trying to add hashtags in the post's `hashtag[]` array as a object with a `num:1` variable to the users `hashtagseen[]` array `if` it is not already in it `else` add 1 the `num` if the hashtag is already in the `hashtagseen[]` array. How do I fix my code? Here is the code, thanks in advanced.

edit: I think I am not finding `post.hashtag` with `this.hashtag` and that is why it will not go to else. Just a guess.

The user object

```
Accounts.createUser({
    username: username,
    password: password,
    email: email,
    profile: {
        hashtagsl:[],
    }
});
```

collections/post.js

```
var post = _.extend(_.pick(postAttributes, 'title', 'posttext','hashtags'), {
   userId: user._id, 
   username: user.username, 
   submitted: new Date().getTime(),
   commentsCount: 0,
   upvoters: [], votes: 0,
 });
```

calling it

```
Meteor.call('addposthashtags',this.hashtags,Meteor.user().profile.hashtagsl);
```

lib/usershash

```
Meteor.methods({
 addposthashtags: function (hashtags,hashtagsl) {
    //supposed to make hashtagseen a array with the names from the hashtagsl object in it
    var hashtagseen = _.pluck(hashtagsl, 'name');
    //supposed to run once per each hashtag in the posts array.
    for (var a = 0; a < hashtags.length; a++) {
        //supposed set hashtagnumber to the number indexOf spits out.
        var hashnumber=hashtagseen.indexOf(hashtags[a]);
        //supposed to check if the current hashtag[a] === a idem in the hashtagseen.
         if(hashnumber===-1){
              var newhashtag = this.hashtags[a];
              //supposed to make the object with a name = to the current hashtags
              Meteor.users.update({"_id": this.userId},{"$push":{"profile.hashtagsl": {name: newhashtag, num: 1}}})
         } else {
              var hashi = hashtagseen[hashnumber];
              //supposed to ad one to the num variable within the current object in hashtagsl
              Meteor.users.update({"_id": this.userId, "profile.hashtagsl.name":hashi},{"$inc":{"profile.hashtagsl.num":1}});
         }
     }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `addposthashtags` function is full of issues. You also haven't provided a "schema" for hashtag objects.

```
addposthashtags: function () {
  for (a = 0; a < this.hashtag.length; a++) {
    // Issue1: You're querying out the user for every iteration of the loop!?
    for (i = 0; i < Meteor.user().profile.hashtagseen.length; i++) {
      // Issue2: You're comparing two _objects_ with ===
      // Issue3: Even if you use EJSON.equals - the `num` property wont match
      // Issue4: You're querying out the user again?
      if (this.hashtag[a] === Meteor.user().profile.hashtagseen[i]) {
        // Issue5 no `var` statement for hashtagseeni?
        // Issue6 You're querying out the user again??
        hashtagseeni = Meteor.user().profile.hashtagseen[i];
        //Issue7 undefined hashtagsli?
        //Issue8 Calling multiple methods for the one action (eg in a loop) is a waste of resources.
        Meteor.call('addseen', hashtagsli);
      } else {
        //Issue9 no `var` statement for newhashtag?
        newhashtag = this.hashtag[a];
        newhashtag.num = 1;
        //Issue8b Calling multiple methods for the one action (eg in a loop) is a waste of resources.
        Meteor.call('updateUser', newhashtag, function (err, result) {
          if (err)
            console.log(err);
        });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Also, the method has similiar issues:

```
addseen: function (hashtagseeni) {
  // Issue10: var `profile` is undefined
  // Issue11: should use `this.userId`
  // Issue12: hashtagseeni wouldn't match profile.hashtagseen due to "num" field.
   Meteor.users.update({"_id": Meteor.userId, "profile.hashtagseen": profile.hashtagseeni}, {"$inc":{"profile.hashtagseen.$.num":1}});
}
```

---

New issues with your new set of code:

```
Meteor.methods({
     addposthashtags: function (hashtags,hashtagsl) {
  //Issue1 `hashtag` is undefined, guessing you mean `hashtags`
  //Issue2 no `var` for a
  for (a = 0; a < hashtag.length; a++) {
    //Issue3 no `var` for i
    //Issue4 Why are you looping through both? 
    // don't you just want to check if hashtag[a] is in hashtagsl? 
    for (i = 0; i < hashtagsl.length; i++) {
      if (hashtags[a] === hashtagsl[i].name) {
        var hashi = hashtagsl[i].name;
        //supposed to ad one to the num variable within the current object in hashtagsl.
        // Issue5: This query wont do what you think. Test until you've got it right.
        Meteor.users.update({"_id": Meteor.userId, 'profile.hashtagsl':hashi}, {"$inc":{"num":1}});
      } else {
        // Issue6 `this.hashtag` isn't defined. guessing you mean `hashtags[a]`
        var newhashtag = this.hashtag[a];
        // Issue7 superfluous statement 
        var newhashtagnum = num = 1;
        // Issue8 Obvious syntax errors
        //   Perhaps try Meteor.users.update({"_id": this.userId},{"$push":{"profile.hashtagsl": {name: newhashtag, num: 1}}}) 
        Meteor.users.update({"_id": Meteor.userId, 'profile'},{"$addToSet":{"hashtagsl"[newhashtag]=newhashtagnum}})
      };
    };
  };
};
});
```

Comment: On the client it runs and sets off this error `Error invoking Method 'userViewedHashTags': Method not found [404] debug.js:41`. On the server it runs and does nothing at all.

Comment: Removed example code; fix the existing issues in your own code first - then if you're still having problems we can debug further.

Comment: I tried to debug the best I could having a error so I can't test to see if it works till its fixed but I don't know what I'm not seeing causing the error.

Comment: @noah just added a new set of comments. What are you using to edit? have you tried Webstorm? or something with decent syntax validation?

Comment: No I will check it out

Comment: Also how would I check without looping through both, and Thanks for all the help.

Comment: maybe, at the start of the function, flatten the list of seen hashtags for easy searching: `var hashtagsseen = _.pluck(hashtagsl, 'name')`. Then use indexOf to see if the current hashtag is in the list, eg. `var hashtagAlreadySeen = (-1 != _.indexOf(hashtagseen, hastags[a]))`.

Comment: I am going to dived them the question into the parts that are not working that I can't figure out. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: could you take a look at the new code? It's still having the same issue.Thanks in advanced.

Comment: @noah looks great! what's with the calls to `hashtag[a].val()`? maybe you should get the value for each of them, before passing them through to the method.

Comment: New edit still not working, but the app runs with no errors almost like its not being called. Can you take a look thanks.

Comment: Hmm.. make sure that the `addposthashtags` isn't in the `client/` or `server/` folder; just put it under `lib/methods/` or something like that.

Comment: make sure it _isn't_. the method needs to be accessible to _both_ so put it under a folder like `lib/methods/`

Comment: No luck. No change under lib.

Comment: well, your code looks fine. Maybe post an example / cut down project on github and I can take a better look.

Comment: Ok I will link it tomorrow. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: [Here is the git](https://github.com/noah2828/debug) the deleted files are old or dupicates.

Answer (score 0):

I see that executing addposthashtags is in the client, and you must to pay attention because this function will execute in minimongo and doesn't work all operations. First you try execute this operation under mongo if it's work you must to create one function inside the folder server.

Add text of the documentation of Minimongo

In this release, Minimongo has some limitations:

> $pull in modifiers can only accept certain kinds of selectors.
>   findAndModify, aggregate functions, and map/reduce aren't supported.
>   All of these will be addressed in a future release. For full Minimongo
>   release notes, see packages/minimongo/NOTES in the repository.
>
> Minimongo doesn't currently have indexes. It's rare for this to be an
>   issue, since it's unusual for a client to have enough data that an
>   index is worthwhile.

You try create one method on the server, with the same operation.

> Server:

```
Meteor.methods({
  updateUser: function (newhashtag) {
    Meteor.users.update(this.userId, 
                       {
                          $addToSet: {'profile.$.hashtagseen': newhashtag}
                       });
  }
});
```

> Client:

```
Meteor.call('updateUser',newhashtag,function(err,result){
        if (err)
                  console.log(err);// there you can print the erro if there are


});
```

Minimongo doesn't support alls operation, for test you can to execute in the console for testing the method if supported. After that you can to execute the operation under mongo directly, that clears your doubts.

Comment: To my understanding you update the user object with `Meteor.users.update` instead of meteor methods  I have done it client side before. What would I put it under in the sever?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you trying  the following

1) Assuming that after `newhashtag=hashtag[a]` you get a JSON object in newhashtag variable, try replacing `newhashtag:{num:1};` with `newhashtag.num = 1` - this will add the num variable to the object and set the value.

1.a) For debugging purposes try adding some `console.log(JSON.stringify(newhashtag));` after each of the two lines where you're setting and changing the newhashtag variable - this way you'll know exactly what you're trying to add to the mongoDB document.

2) The update to increment the views also doesn't seem to me that will work. Couple of things to note here  - `$set:{'profile.hashtagseen[i]':num++}` - MongoDB won't be able to identify the 'i' in 'profile.hashtagseen[i]' and 'num++' is not how increments are done in Mongo.
I'd suggest you look into the [$inc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) and to the [positional update](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) documentation of MongoDB.

Your final increment update statement will look something like

`Meteor.users.update({"_id": Meteor.userId, "profile.hashtagseen": profile.hashtagseen[i]}, {"$inc":{"profile.hashtagseen.$.num":1}});`

Comment: For some reason nothing is getting to the else statement but still nothing in the hashtagseen array so it should be but its appears to be stuck on the if.